How can I make my three-way switched outlets always hot?
I have two 3 way switches which control all outlets (top half only). I'm looking to completely eliminate these switches and make all outlets permanently hot (top and bottom) by removing both switches (rather than replacing 8 outlets).
This (crude) diagram shows what I'm dealing with.
I have a 14x2 Load wire coming in, where white is HOT. It gets tied into 14x3 black wire, which I assume is then sent over to the other box into a switch. from that switch the Black/White/Red are all tied into a single pole. There is also a single pole back at my original location with the 14x2 black wire (not hot) and the red/white put into another single pole switch.
Any advice would be helpful

You require a light controlled by a switch by the door.  This can be a ceiling light or a light plugged in an outlet.  Turn off the breaker for the outlets and take them out of the box(without removing the wires) and edit pictures into your question.  I believe it should be simple to have most of outlets done like you want, with this one or two left for lights.

Why would you want to pull the breakers out of their sockets?! This requires removal of the dead front of the electric panel. This is a hige increase in effort and of risk for no siginificant benefit. Just switching off the breaker or breakers is sufficient. OP should get a non contact voltage tester to confirm power is off. Should have a plug-in circuit tester to confirm connections are correct.

Are all these receptacles (both switched hot uppers and always hot lowers) on one breaker? If so, then there would not be any need to replace the receptacles to restore the connections of upper to lower hots. To restore any receptacle to always hot, just disconnect the switched hot (and cap that) and use a wire jumper from lower to upper. That way you could leave one receptacle switched and have all the others always hot.

Before doing anything try out the proposal to disable the switches by buying two shabbos light switch covers. Turn the switch on and put on the cover. You could just leave it that way so that you will not have messed with the wiring. Or jsut put tape over the switches if they are stad toggle.

I'll be installing overhead lights in this room, so I'm just trying to get all of the outlets hot always rather than dealing with a switch/receptacle. I would think i can do that from the switch side, rather than opening all 8 outlets. By somehow just connecting the circuit so its no longer switched

Do you plan on using the existing switch boxes for the new overhead lights? Or are you going to install new switch boxes? The problem with using the existing boxes to contain both the original wiring and the new wiring is the box would likely be overfilled with wires.

To underscore the approach described by @JimStewart — each receptacle has an always-hot feed to its lower outlet; just use that to feed the upper outlet, too.

Old house, so there is no always hot feed to my switch boxes. There was a switch loop in place, which i'm working through

OP said the lower receptacles of each duplex receptacle are always hot. So just disconnect each switched hot at the receptacle and put in a jumper wire from each lower receptacle to each upper that you want to be always on. If you have one or two that you want to leave switched, then don't do this on those. This way you won't have to install a ceiling light and can continue to use the wall switch as is to control lamps pugged into those receptacles.


I have two 3 way switches which control all outlets (top half only). I'm looking to completely eliminate these switches and make all outlets permanently hot (top and bottom) by removing both switches

just remove the 3-way switches, connect line to either one of the travelers at that switch location and then at the other location that traveler to the wire that goes to the outlets.  That's it.


I have a 14x2 Load wire coming in, where white is HOT. It gets tied into 14x3 black wire, which I assume is then sent over to the other box into a switch. from that switch the Black/White/Red are all tied into a single pole. There is also a single pole back at my original location with the 14x2 black wire (not hot) and the red/white put into another single pole switch.

this last part doesn't make sense.  Things started off making sense (your diagram notwithstanding) with 3-way switches controlling just the top half of a bunch of duplex receptacles, simple enough.  But then you say a single pole back at my original location.  If you have a single-pole switch (i.e. simple on/off) and you want to make the load always hot then you just remove the switch and connect the wires together.  And if you were to draw a more clear diagram and had one that mimicked the pic I linked here (any 3-way wiring diagram) that would go a long way.  From what you've described I don't see how there is any kind of problem to an get always hot situation.

The switch loop is what's throwing me. I just want power to all of my receptacles not controlled by any switching. My terrible drawing certainly doesn't help! this guide could help me think about how the power is moving

just want power to all of my receptacles not controlled by any switching - then I'm pretty sure what I've written is your answer. If you still don't comprehend this look up some vids on youtube for tutorials.

and you also have to be correct in what you are thinking the wiring/switching in question is; you used the word assume in your explanation.  For starters, stuff like this you should not "assume" on.  It either is or you don't know.

Thank you, i'll do some more research

pretty funny the home improvement police edit my answer for using the word crude referring to your diagram, like it was derogatory, when the OP asking referred to his own diagram as crude.  Feels like discrimination, not letting me use the same exact words the OP used.

Your 3-way switches are operating on a "switch loop", where Hot from one of the outlet boxes is supplied on the White wire (which really should have some colored tape wrapped around it to indicate that it's been repurposed as Hot), and "Switched Hot" is returned back to the outlets on the Black wire.
So the simplest way to make all the outlets Always-On is to disconnect both the White Incoming Hot and Black Returning Switched Hot from the switch and wire-nut them together in the box.


This house had lots of switch loops, so this makes sense. so presumably i can just literally remove all 14x3 and all switches and tie the power onto itself (white to black)? I think thats what your diagram shows. This would eliminate any connection to any 14x3 wire

Yes. Once you've looped the power back from White to Black, the rest of the original 3-way switch circuit will no longer be connected to anything and can be removed if you like.

Thank you. I plan on using the power from the switch loop to power some new lights. Can i just tap off the switch loop and use that to power my new equipment?

No you can't (at least not as-is). The switch loop currently does not give you a Neutral wire to use to power anything. But if you find the other end of that switch loop and rewired the cable such that White became Neutral and Black became Hot, then you could use it to power other things.

Thank you, i've begun opening all of my outlets and have found my switch loop. I'll work from there to try to get this fixed up!
